# What should be the http response code for an endpoint like 'CheckedOutBy' in a scenario where the file is not checked out?

Tags: rest

I have an endpoint which returns the details of the user who checked-out the file, for this i am returning 200-Ok response with relevant payload (if file is checkedout).  I was wondering what should the appropriate response code be for a scenario where the file is not checked-out.  I could use 200-ok and have empty payload, but is there a better way of conveying this through the Http response code?

Answer (score 1):

> is there a better way of conveying this through the Http response code?

No - the correct way to handle this is in the response payload.

HTTP response codes are metadata of the [transfer-of-documents-over-a-network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m08s) domain.  The client asked for a document, you have a document, here it is: 200.

The "correct" way to handle this is to design your document schema so that you can use it to describe everything the document needs to describe.

Think "web page" - this is what the page looks like when something is checked out, that is what the page looks like when something is not checked out, but "here is the latest copy of the page" would always be 200.

---

(Note: there are lots of examples on the web that don't actually do this the correct way.  When people are writing bespoke client code for your API, doing this correctly isn't necessarily *important*.)